# Объясните, пожалуйста, что значит эта строка в коде

Tags: c, инспекция-кода

Вот этот код

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{

    printf("Введите имена:\n");
    string name = GetString();
    printf("%c", toupper(name[0])); 
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(name); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (name[i] == ' ' && name[i+1] != '\0')
      {
        printf("%c", toupper(name[i+1]));
        i++;
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Приведенная ниже строка

```
printf("%c", toupper(name[0]));
```

к примеру, говорит: выведи на экран символ, который соответствует первой букве переменной `name`, и сделай это капсом, будь любезен.

А вот эта строка вызывает у меня несколько вопросов. Не могли бы вы простым языком объяснить, что она делает?

```
if (name[i] == ' ' && name[i+1] != '\0')
```

Comment: Что именно не ясно в этой строке? Откройте, наконец, любую книгу для начинающих программистов по C..

Comment: И почему вы, вообще, вытаскиваете чью-то чужую некорректную программу и просите вам ее объяснить вместо того, чтобы самому написать программу?

Comment: Ну почему же Вы  решили, что перед тем как лезть на форумы, я не прочитал "любую книгу для начинающих" ? Вот, к примеру, из одной такой книги я узнал, что \0 обозначает конец строки. А тут мне сообщают совсем другое. Там же я узнал что "пробел" записывается как " ", а тут кавычки одинарные. Вот именно это вопросы и вызвало

Comment: Это лишь означает, что вам недостаточно один раз прочитать книгу для начинающих по C. Вам надо перечитать ее несколько раз.

Comment: Посоветуете какую-то конкретную?

Comment: Я уже очень давно никаких книг по C не просматривал, а потому ничего не могу посоветовать.

Answer (score 3):

```
if    (name[i]    ==  ' '    &&     name[i+1]     !=    '\0')
если   i-й символ -  пробел, И  следующий за ним  не   нулевой
```

(вспомним, что нулевой символ - это символ конца строки)

Так понятнее? :)

Comment: Но разве \0 - это не конец строки?

Comment: А что такое конец строки, как не нулевой символ?...

Comment: Эмм..эээ... Пойду учить мат часть :с